# How can I block all ports with PF except port 80 and 443?

Tags: network, security, firewall

How can I block/close (or drop all the packets coming from) all ports with PF except TCP port 80 and TCP 443?
So I only want to make use of port 80 and 443 via TCP.

I tried this, but I receive an error

```
sudo gedit /etc/pf.conf
```

Content:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

set block-policy drop
pass in all keep state
pass out all keep state
block in proto tcp to port 80
block in proto tcp to port 443

block drop from any to 93.184.220.29
block drop from any to 93.184.220.70
```

The error:

```
sudo pfctl -v -n -f /etc/pf.conf
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

set block-policy drop
/etc/pf.conf:8: Rules must be in order: options, normalization, queueing, translation, filtering
```

I also tried the approach described in the link but that did also not work.
[Link to repo](https://github.com/ozkansener/Macdroppackets)

Comment: The link you tried to use (https://github.com/ozkansener/Macdroppackets) is a very bad use of C and PF. The obtained PF file doesn't preserve the system definitions, and build a stupid list of blocking one port at a time among 65536.

Comment: About the error message you got, I would have written it the same way. The `set block-policy drop` option is badly placed. What part of this error message would like to be clarified?

Comment: Beware, your other rules are dangerous and in the wrong order, but `pfctl` won't give you an error message about this. From `pfctl` point of vue it is legit to let all packet pass.

Comment: How would you suggest me to do it? I am really a beginner with PF.